# fetchIfNeeded() for ParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform

I Created DataModel like below in  Parse.com

```
Conversation 
objectId startedBy 

Message
objectId containedInConversation(Pointer to Conversation) content(Pointer to TextMessageContent)

TextMessageContent
objectId text
```

I have code like this

```
ParseQuery parseQueryMessage=new ParseQuery("Message");
parseQueryMessage.include("content")
parseQueryMessage.include("containedInConversation");

List<ParseObject> messages;
messages=parseQueryMessage.find();

ParseObject message=messages.get(0);
ParseObject textMessageContent=message.getParseObject("content");

ParseObject conversation=message.getParseObject("containedInConversation");

System.out.println(textMessageContent.getString("text")); // gives output 
System.out.println(conversation.getString("startedBy")); // gives exception
```

for second `Println` statement i am getting Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParseObject has no data for this key.  Call fetchIfNeeded() to get the data.
```

I have a confusion here.

For `textMessageContent` ,I didnt call `fetchIfNeeded()` But i am getting output
But For conversation object,It is not working. Why  ???

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [fetchIfNeeded()](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#fetchIfNeeded--) since the object from the relation isn't fetched by default.

So your call should be:

```
ParseObject textMessageContent=message.fetchIfNeeded()getParseObject("content");
```